# Negative binomial Anscombe residuals

Tags: generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data, symmetry

I'm working on a generalised linear regression model, using the so called NB2 model. In other words, I'm using a negative binomial regression model for count data. I would like to graph a normal probability plot in order to asses the goodness of fit of my model, using the Anscombe residuals.

However, unfortunately I was not able to find anything about those residuals on the Internet for the case of the negative binomial distribution. Any suggestions?

Comment: I know this is a late response, but I believe you will find the following paper useful: Best D, Rayner J, Thas O (2009) Anscombe’s Tests of Fit for the Negative Binomial Distribution. Journal of Statistical Theory and Practice doi: [10.1080/15598608.2009.10411946](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/15598608.2009.10411946)

Answer (score 1):

Anscombe suggested two symmetrizing transforms for the negative binomial with mean $m$ and known exponent $k$* in his 1948 paper[1]:

1. $\ln(y+\frac{k}{2})$; with variance approximately $\psi'(k)$. This transformation approximates the more accurate but more complicated one below -
2. $2\sinh^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{y+c}{k-2c}}$, for $k>2$ where if $k$ is large $c\approx\frac{3}{8}$

   In this case variance is also approximately $\psi'(k)$. If $k$ is not small this is approximately $\frac{1}{k-\frac12}$, but the function $\psi'$ is often available (it is in R for example).

   Anscombe later suggests that a slightly smaller $c$ might be more suitable, and suggests rounding $c$ to a single decimal place; this would suggest $c=0.3$ might be a reasonable choice.

Note that the approximation in 1. is obtained by setting $c=k/2$ in 2., which is not generally very close to the optimum but may be more convenient.

* Specifically: $\Pr(Y = r) = \frac{\Gamma(r+k)}{r! \, \Gamma(k)}  \left(\frac{m}{k+m}\right)^r \left(\frac{k}{k+m}\right)^k  \quad\text{for }r = 0, 1, 2, \dotsc$

This is the same as the pmf listed in the Wikipedia article on the negative binomial under [Alternative formulations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations) at the fifth bullet point ("*In negative binomial regression, ...*"), but with the roles of $r$ and $k$ interchanged (so here $k$ is the shape parameter and the variance of this NB is $m+\frac{m^2}{k}$. (I've written it this way to fit with Anscombe's notation.)

Anscombe begins the paper with the transformation I list second, and initially gives it without the factor of 2 out the front (which only impacts the variance). He adds the factor of 2 later (presumably because it enables him to deal with both transformations together in several parts). 
Once standardized to a residual, the factor of 2 makes no difference, of course.

In each case, the usual Anscombe residual would be

$\qquad r^A_i=\frac{t(y_i)-t(\mu_i)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(t(y_i))}}$

where $t$ is either the transformation in 1. or in 2., the Var term is replaced by its approximation above, and of course we would replace $\mu_i$ by its fitted value.

[1]: Anscombe, F. J. (1948),
"The Transformation of Poisson, Binomial and Negative-Binomial Data,"
*Biometrika*, Vol. **35**, No. *3/4* (Dec.), pp. 246-254

Comment: I take it the idea here is that doing this will make the residuals sufficiently normal that a qq-plot becomes viable as a way to assess the validity of the NB model. Is that the gist of it?

Comment: @gung presumably, but I wouldn't put much weight on it if the mean is small or the $k$ parameter is small -- any more than I would in the case of Poisson regression with small mean, but perhaps even less so. In some situations it may help to indicate particular kinds of problems.